# When does the live USB ask if I want to re-install?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

Ubuntu is not booting and is hanging on the splash screen or getting a black screen.

Grub seemed to operate but none of the operations in grub alone fixed the issue. So I've booted to a live USB drive with 14.04.02 LTS.

I want to re-install and not blow all my files and settings away if possible.

I've started the install process but I'm worried that it is doing a full install and all I want to do is a reinstall. How many questions into the installation before it starts to "install" or it identifies I have Ubuntu installed and I want to re-install?

Do I need to make sure I have the exact same version of Ubuntu 14.04.01 or is there a plain 14.04 version I should be using on my live usb?

Comment: I don't think there's a "reinstall". There's "Install over", which will format everything, "Install alongside", which will create a new partition if possible and install to that and "Something else".

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/196740/how-to-fix-an-ubuntu-system-when-it-wont-boot/

Answer (score 1):

It seems I should get the option to reinstall on the "Installation Type" menu.

[image]

I've since confirmed Ubuntu is installed, the installation from the live USB did not detect the current installation and did not show the options in that picture. I have since simply blown away all fglrx drivers using [these instructions](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Trusty_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx). Default drivers are now displaying the gui.

Answer (score 0):

Having recently installed various versions of Ubuntu before settling on Lubuntu; I can say the only issue I had was ensuring my USB pen drive was given boot priority in the BIOS.

I also noticed that there was a longish delay before the installation screen came up and I had to give ample time for it to initiate.

The installation screen should give you some choices: [install dialog](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1349879961.png).

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall

Comment: It seems I should get the option to reinstall on the "Installation Type" menu.  http://cdn3.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/650x320xreinstall-ubuntu-while-keeping-files-and-programs.png.pagespeed.ic.tNv2sjZKZg.png  I've since confirmed Ubuntu is installed, the installation from the live USB did not detect the current installation and did not show the options in that picture.  I have since simply blown away all fglrx drivers using these instructions: http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Trusty_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx  Default drivers are now displaying the gui.